# Highly customizable C++ GUI library?

Tags: c++

Is there any C++ GUI lib here that is fast, has highly customizable looks (like Swing) and ofcourse, of much higher level of abstraction then Win32?

I'm a complete begginer in c++ but loved Java+Swing combo very much for their customizability.

Simply put, I want the lib to be easy to learn, can be customized by simply subclassing and overiding their painting (like Swing) and free :)

Please help me!

P.S. I use orwell dev-c++ portable fork with 32 bit gcc. if that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qt is what you're looking for: http://qt-project.org

Comment: Would it let me customize controls like sliders (seekbars), scrollbars, textareas etc.?
I want to handle their paintings/drawings so that I can sort of "skin" them.

Comment: @KochaSapam: Yes. Qt allows full customisation (It needs that itself to provide a fully native look and feel on all its supported platforms)

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty: [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/), and many many more. All easy to find in short time using any search engine.

Comment: Downloaded wxWidgets, doesnt seem to suite me.